# How to find index of a value in an array ignoring index of a specified value

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

Can Linq be used to find the index of a value from an array while ignoring indexes of a particular value?

Eg.
array = {1,2,3,4,0,5,0,6,7}

index of 6 is 7
if I choose to ignore the index of all zeros
and instead return 5 as the index of 6
by counting over zero but keeping 0 in the array.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want that value?

Comment: I don't that value exactly. what I want is to insert a value into the index ignoring all zeros(e.g. array[4] = 2 will insert and replace 5 with 2.

Comment: I want to modify a copy of an array which has been altered.

Comment: What does "ignoring all the zeroes" mean? That you want to return an updated array with a value replaced and without the zeroes? Or just that you want to replace a value?

Answer (score 1):

`FastReplaceFirstMatch` is likely the fastest option for your very specific problem (mentioned in a comment to one of the other responses).

I've included some LINQ based solutions (which will be much faster than other `ToList` based solutions) to your specified question (in your question, not the comment clarification) as well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    public static class GenericExtensions
    {
        public static int IndexExcludingValue<T>(this IEnumerable<T> test, T valueToFind, T valueToExclude) where T : struct
        {
            return test.Where(z => !Equals(z, valueToExclude))
                .Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                .FirstOrDefault(z => Equals(z.value, valueToFind))?.index ?? -1;
        }

        public static T[] FastReplaceFirstMatch<T>(this T[] test, T valueToFind, T valueToReplace) where T : struct
        {
            var hasBeenReplaced = false;

            var index = Array.FindIndex(test, z => Equals(z, valueToFind));

            if (index != -1)
            {
                test[index] = valueToReplace;
            }

            return test;
        }


        public static IEnumerable<T> ReplaceFirstMatch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> test, T valueToFind, T valueToReplace) where T : struct
        {
            var hasBeenReplaced = false;

            return test
                .Select(value =>
                    {
                        if (!hasBeenReplaced && Equals(value, valueToFind))
                        {
                            hasBeenReplaced = true;
                            value = valueToReplace;
                        }
                        return value;
                    });
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static int[] bob = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 7 };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(bob.IndexExcludingValue(6, 0));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", bob.ReplaceFirstMatch(6, 8).ToArray()));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", bob.FastReplaceFirstMatch(6, 10)));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that help @Godon2020 ?

Answer (score 1):

e.g.,

```
var x = new[] { 0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6 };
```

using ToList()

```
x.Where(i => i != 0).ToList().IndexOf(5);
```

using ToArray()

```
Array.FindIndex(x.Where(i => i != 0).ToArray(), i => i == 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

All i can think of at this moment is to use this to ignore specific elements on the array:

```
array.Where(e => e != 0);
```

And then this to get the index:

```
array.Where(e => e != 0).ToList().IndexOf(6);
```

Comment: So... where is the index returned?

Comment: @MetaColon edited, i assumed he already knows how to get the index

Comment: Forgot the .ToList() sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another, in my opinion easier, solution: You can again eliminate the zeros, convert the resulting enumerable to a list then and use `IndexOf` on this list:

```
array.Where(x => x != 0)
   .ToList().IndexOf(6); //Results in 5 as well
```

As another, in my opinion more beautiful, solution, you could write an extension method like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int IndexOfIgnoring<T> (this IEnumerable<T> collection, T indexOf, T toIgnore) =>
        collection.Where (arg => !Equals (arg, toIgnore)).ToList ().IndexOf (indexOf);
}
```

You can use this like that then:

```
static void Main (string [] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine ($"{new [] {1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 7}.IndexOfIgnoring (6, 0)}");
    Console.ReadLine ();
}
```

You can read more about extension methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

**EDIT** As the comment of the OP asked me, here's a solution, to set items at the index, which ignored specific items.

Therefore I'd like to work with extension methods again:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int IndexOfIgnoring<T> (this IEnumerable<T> collection, T indexOf, T toIgnore) =>
        collection.Where (arg => !Equals (arg, toIgnore)).ToList ().IndexOf (indexOf);

    public static int GetRealIndexOfIgnoring<T> (this IEnumerable<T> collection, int indexIgnored, T toIgnore)
        => collection.Select ((t, i) => new Tuple<T, int> (t, i)).Where (arg => !Equals (arg.Item1, toIgnore)).
                      ToList () [indexIgnored].Item2;

    public static IEnumerable<T> SetAtIndexOfIgnoring<T> (this IEnumerable<T> collection, int indexIgnored, T toIgnore, T toSet)
    {
        var enumerable = collection as IList<T> ?? collection.ToList ();
        return enumerable.Select ((t, i) => i == GetRealIndexOfIgnoring (enumerable, indexIgnored, toIgnore) ? toSet : t);
    }
}
```

Which we can use like this:

```
static void Main (string [] args)
{
    var collection = new [] {1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 7};
    var ignoredIndex = collection.IndexOfIgnoring (6, 0);
    Console.WriteLine ($"{ignoredIndex}");
    collection = collection.SetAtIndexOfIgnoring(ignoredIndex, 0, 10).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", collection));
    Console.ReadLine ();
}
```

Which outputs:

```
5
1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 0, 10, 7
```

Comment: what if i want to insert a value into index (e.g. array[4] = 2 will insert and replace 5 with 2.

Comment: @Godon2020 I'm not quite sure wether I understand what you mean, but I guess, you just had to reexecute it.

Comment: what I mean is instead of getting the value from the index after ignoring all zeros, how do I insert into the index also ignoring all zero indices. Hence (e.g. array[4] = 2 will insert and replace 5 with 2, instead of 0 with 2)

Comment: @mjwills depends on what you expect it to do.

Comment: @mjwills It is distinguishable, as the count of a collection isn't a valid index for it (the maximum valid index is count - 1)